# Is this c# class/method thread-safe and concurrent access safe?

Tags: c#, class, methods, static, thread-safety

In the code below, is attachments object thread-safe? If calling code make changes to the attachments object while application running multiple threads, what may happen?

Thanks.

```
public static class Util {
    public static int AddMessage(string message, IEnumerable<FileAttachment> attachments, Dictionary<int, object> customFieldValues = null, int? assigneeUserId = null) {
        foreach (FileAttachment current2 in attachments) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the code below, is attachments object thread-safe? And if calling code make changes to the attachments object while application running multiple threads, what may happen?

There is nothing that suggests that `attachments` is thread safe here.  If other threads have access to those instances, and change the properties within those objects, bad things could happen.

A simple example - if the actual enumerable happens to be a `List<T>`, and another thread adds or removes an attachment, the `foreach` loop will throw as it enumerates due to the underlying collection changing...

Comment: Thanks. And if this code is placed in a website that is hosted under IIs, and multiple users access the same page (I mean the same code) at the same time,  what may happend? is this concurrent-acess safe thorugh a website hosted under IIs?

Comment: @stacker if you are using ASP.NET be aware that a worker process can recycle at any time, causing your in-memory data to be lost without warning.

Comment: @stacker There's no way to know whether this is thread safe or not by the code posted, though if you're workign with shared/static data, it's most likely not thread safe.